# Securely sending message from a react app to a chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, sendmessage

I have a chrome extension with manifest.json, but in order to be used, a user needs to be authenticated. If an unauthenticated user clicks the extension icon, they are redirected to a login (react) page. On successful login i want the react page to securely pass the info (login token) to the extension that the user is now authenticated. How can i go about this; to pass the sensitive token from the react to the extension. I am using MV3 in my extension

in my app.tsx below

```
if (session) {
      const token = session.getToken();
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'setToken', data: token }, (res) => {
        // ...
        
      });
    }
```

I cannot use the `chrome.runtime` as above (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')) since i do not have the Chrome extension APIs in my react app

Comment: 1) Anything your page does or sends can be intercepted by another extension's content script running in this page and there's nothing you can do to prevent it. The only secure method is to make the token on the server so that the extension uses `fetch` in its background script. 2) To use chrome.runtime.sendMessage in React app, even though it's not secure,  declare [externally_connectable in the extension](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#external-webpage).